Статичные кнопки в форме Qt Desginer отображаются не так как мне надо
Сделал программу в Qt Desginer с компоновкой виджетов, всё хорошо работает.
Но как только я пытаюсь сделать что-то подобное, то у меня не получается.
Т.е. В работающей версии кнопки статичны в зависимости от расширения программы, пример:


Можно заметить, что кнопки остаются одного размера всегда.
К сожалению, как бы я не пытался, я не могу добиться того же результата, пересмотрел все настройки которые были, но не получается так сделать.


Вот пример, как получается сейчас:


Помогите пожалуйста, что я упускаю?
Работающая версия.ui
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>433</width>
    <height>576</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">#centralwidget{background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);}</string>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>165</width>
        <height>38</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">color: rgb(151, 102, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Конвертация YML в JSON</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>421</width>
        <height>104</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(23, 25, 33);</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
       <item>
        <widget class="Line" name="line">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>61</width>
             <height>60</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>61</width>
             <height>60</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/file/images/yml3.png);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>271</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>291</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);
color: rgb(162, 162, 162);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;</string>
           </property>
           <property name="cursorPosition">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="alignment">
            <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
           </property>
           <property name="placeholderText">
            <string>Название файла.yml</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>61</width>
             <height>60</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>61</width>
             <height>60</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/file/images/json3.png);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="Line" name="line_2">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>414</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
       <item>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>13</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="addFile">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>211</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <weight>75</weight>
             <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">#addFile {
    background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#addFile:hover{
background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Выбрать файл</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="convert">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>211</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <weight>75</weight>
             <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">#convert {
background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#convert:hover{
background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Конвертировать</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="add">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>211</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <weight>75</weight>
             <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">#add {
background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#add:hover{
background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Добавить Json в Базу даных</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>40</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>200</width>
             <height>200</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>9999</width>
             <height>9999</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/file/images/gnvclogo.png);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>40</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="info">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>211</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <weight>75</weight>
             <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">#info {
background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#info:hover{
background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Дополнительная информация</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="../qrc_files/file.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>



Не работающая версия .ui:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>443</width>
    <height>592</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">#centralwidget{background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);}</string>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>165</width>
        <height>38</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">color: rgb(151, 102, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Конвертация YML в JSON</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>421</width>
        <height>104</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(23, 25, 33);</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
       <item>
        <widget class="Line" name="line">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>61</width>
             <height>60</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>61</width>
             <height>60</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/file/images/yml3.png);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>271</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>291</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(66, 71, 90);
color: rgb(162, 162, 162);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;</string>
           </property>
           <property name="cursorPosition">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="alignment">
            <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
           </property>
           <property name="placeholderText">
            <string>Название файла.yml</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>61</width>
             <height>60</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>61</width>
             <height>60</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/file/images/json3.png);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>40</width>
             <height>20</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="Line" name="line_2">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>414</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(17, 18, 21);</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
       <item>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>13</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="addFile">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>211</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <weight>75</weight>
             <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">#addFile {
    background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#addFile:hover{
background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Выбрать файл</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="convert">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>211</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <weight>75</weight>
             <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">#convert {
background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#convert:hover{
background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Конвертировать</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="add">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>211</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <weight>75</weight>
             <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">#add {
background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#add:hover{
background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Добавить Json в Базу даных</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>40</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>200</width>
             <height>200</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>9999</width>
             <height>9999</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/file/images/gnvclogo.png);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>20</width>
             <height>40</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="info">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>211</width>
             <height>31</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <weight>75</weight>
             <bold>true</bold>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">#info {
background-color: rgb(151, 102, 255);
/*background-color: rgb(0, 139, 247);*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 15px; /* Задайте радиус, чтобы сделать края овальными */
padding: 2px;}


#info:hover{
background-color: rgb(164, 205, 217);
}</string>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Дополнительная информация</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>


Пояснение вопроса:

На работающей версии, все кнопки остаются одного размера всегда, при этом сдвигаются в середину, когда происходит масштабирование окна (2-й по счёту скриншот).
А вот вторая версия, не рабочая - кнопки всегда увеличиваются по ширине окна, в скринах которые я предоставил это отчётливо видно. (4-й по счёту скриншот, окно справа)

Нужно сделать так, чтобы на (четвёртом скриншоте) кнопки правого окна оставались одинакового размера и сдвигались к центру во время масштабирования окна.

сделайте как хорошо, а как плохо не делайте (ц)

Работающая версия.ui - это хорошо, но вам надо предоставить версию, которая демонстрирует проблему и хорошо рассказать что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

@S.Nick в течении полутора часа, я внесу правки и уточню свой вопрос

@S.Nick Я добавил все правки, если вам что-то будет не хватать, напишите пожалуйста. Надеюсь я достаточно ясно изложил свою проблему.

Сделайте одинаковыми максимальные и минимальные размеры кнопок, а сами кнопки поместите в какой-нибудь контейнер (например QWidget), в котором установите размещение по горизонтали (QHBoxLayout) для того чтобы справа и слева от кнопки добавить QSpacerItem (они будут держдать кнопки по центру) и придет к вам внутренний покой

@AlexanderChernin К сожалению, ваш вариант не работает. В этом случае Виджет будет растягиваться, а кнопки всегда будут находится слева и к центру двигаться не будут. Я предоставил рабочий файл выше и обошёлся там без ограничений максимального размера, правда не совсем помню, как я это сделал

@НикитаПфейфер все работает (уж более 20 лет как :) ), я дополнил комментарий. )

@AlexanderChernin Замечательный комментарий, выглядит очень даже хорошо. Но в своём примере, я как-то и без этого обошёлся, вот хочется вспомнить, как! Спасибо за вашу отзывчивость. Если не найду нужное мне решение, обязательно воспользуюсь вашим

Да, вместо спейсеров можно установить https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#setAlignment-1 в Qt::AlignHCenter как, собственно, у вас указано в работающей ui (это наверное то и есть, что вы забыли). В целом тут ничего сложного нет, немного поиграйтесь в QtDesigner и все получится

@AlexanderChernin Это настройка для виджета?

@AlexanderChernin Не могу понять, где эта настройка, и для какого элемента она предназначена

Эта опция устанавливается при ручном редактировании ui-файла (в самом редакторе QtDesigner ее нет). Под тэгом layout найдите тэг item и установите у него атрибут alignment  <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">. Либо тоже самое можно сделать через код, вызовом layout.setAligmnet(Qt.AlignHCenter)

Это очень странно, если оно устанавливается вручную, то почему в Qt Designer у меня отображается всё по разному. Можете посмотреть на (четвёртый скриншот) слева как надо, а справа не так

@S.Nick Здравствуйте! А как вы думаете, в чём проблема? У меня есть предположение, что в рабочей версии есть некий баг, правда я не понимаю, как он появился

Никита Пфейфер, я не понимаю о каком баге вы говорите. Ничто ниоткуда не появляется и ничто никуда не исчезает.  Пожалуйста, прочитайте мои комментарии, которые я написал ниже своего ответа.

В работающей версии


Не работающая версия


@НикитаПфейфер что не так?

@НикитаПфейфер я ответил на ваш вопрос? Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете,
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Да, кажется вы ответили на мой вопрос. Я завтра обязательно посмотрю и сразу отвечу. Извините, за долгий ответ, я работал и не мог зайти посмотреть

Я проверил, это действительно то, что я забыл. Спасибо!

@НикитаПфейфер  пожалуйста
